# Do I need to include this field in table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 5 db tables but the issue I have is with the `Student_Answer` Table, I do not know if I should include the `SessionId` field or not in that table because we will know which session each question belongs to through foreign keys. I thought I may as well ask to make sure:

Below are tables:

Session Table

```
SessionId (auto PK) SessionName
1                   DOEEO
2                   EFOEO
3                   EOEOW
```

Question Table:

```
QuestionId (Auto PK) QuestionNo  QuestionContent  SessionId (Fk)
1                    1           Question 1       1
2                    2           Question 2       1
3                    3           Question 3       2
4                    4           Question 4       2           
5                    5           Question 5       3
```

Answer Table:

```
AnswerId (Auto PK)  Answer  QuestionId(Fk) 
1                   A       1
2                   C       1
3                   B       2
4                   C       3
5                   A       4
6                   D       5
7                   E       5
```

Student Table:

```
StudentId (Auto PK)  StudentForename   StudentSurname
1                    Joe               Price
2                    Kyle              May
3                    Mark              Knowles
```

Student_Answer Table:

```
StudentAnswerId (auto PK) SessionId(FK) QuestionId (FK) StudentAnswer  StudentId (FK)
1                         1             1               C              1
2                         1             1               B              1
3                         1             1               A              2
4                         1             1               C              2
5                         1             2               C              1
6                         1             2               B              2
7                         2             3               A              1
8                         2             3               C              2
```

Comment: is the session different from question and answer?

Comment: it really depends on your business logic. in your case, i don't think that is necessarily to have a session id as foreign key in student table; unless your system need to frequently navigate to session through student.

Comment: then if that's the case then you don't need to add `SessionId` on table `Student_Answer` since you have already define it on `Question` table.

Comment: @JW ok that seems cool, That is what Dan has said as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only do you not need the SessionID field in the StudentAnswer table, you don't need the StudentAnswerId field either.  All you need are the QuestionID, StudentId, and StudentAnswer.  Your primary key would be the QuestionId and StudentId.

This is called a many to many relationship.

Comment: Hi, I heard when creating primary keys, it is best for each table to just include primary keys with no meanings, in other words just include a field which is primary key which is auto so that for each row it has its own unique id, I heard this is more secure. Does it really matter if I do or do not have StudentAnswerId field? Because I have done this for all my tables in my whole table (24 tables)

Comment: @user1881090 What happens if you end up with two students who have the same first and last name?  How would you distinguish between them if you didn't have the unique id field?  And although you can argue that it's more secure when the id has no meaning, that's not the primary reason why it shouldn't have a meaning.  What if the primary key was the combination of first and last name; then what happens to all your foreign keys once someone's name changes?  The reason the primary key should be meaningless is because there should NEVER be a reason to change it once it's been set.

Comment: @user1881090, you do want a unique identifier, but it has to make sense.  In this situation if you add a field for that purpose, it allows you to add data of a student submitting two answers to the same question.  Unless that's permitted in real life, that field is doing more harm than good.

Comment: @DanBracuk Each student has their own studentId as their primary key so that if two students known as Dave Smith, one will be studentid 24 and other will be 34 for example. Plus even though I did not include it in table above, each student has their own Student Number, so first dave smith could be u4992, second dave smith could be u3929

Answer (score 0):

If you did it would go against normalization rules, so strictly speaking the answer would be no.  However, that's not to say that denormalization is always bad.  The primary problem with doing that is that it becomes more difficult to detect problems in your application if/when you forget to update both numbers.

If it's impossible for a session number of a question to change once it's been set then this isn't as big of an issue, but if it can change and then you don't change it in the other table then that's a problem... this is why it's better to just have it in one place.

Having said all that, I am wondering whether you are keeping the session in the best place to begin with.  Can you explain why a session should be tied to the question rather than the answer or the student?  Without knowing your system, my guess would be that the session ought to be saved on the student table rather than the question table.

Edit: Instead of adding the SessionId to the student answer table, typically what you'll want to do is just create a view that contains all the information you need.  If the view is only for human readability then you wouldn't even need to include the id fields, but just show the actual session name in the view.  However, if you're just trying to create something that makes coding easier then you could include the id too as well in the view.

Comment: A session is another word for exam. I have a table called Student_Session where it uses SessionId and StudentId to determine which students take which sessions. I have set answers depending on questionid which is pretty much same situation as this